# How to find the eigenvector corresponding to the lowest eigenvalue in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I could just look for the lowest non-zero eigenvalue and then get the corresponding eigenvector.

Do you know of any other cleaner method to get this?

lowindex from eigen() is apparently ignored in the current implementation :(

Answer (score 2):

As it [says in the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#eigen):

> **eigenvalues** – output vector of eigenvalues of the same type as src; the eigenvalues are stored in the descending order.

and

> **eigenvectors** – output matrix of eigenvectors; it has the same size and type as src; the eigenvectors are stored as subsequent matrix
>   rows, in the same order as the corresponding eigenvalues

So the lowest eigenvalue is simply the last element in the **eigenvalues** vector and the corresponding eigenvector is the last row of the **eigenvectors** matrix.

If the last eigenvalue is zero (i.e. your input is singular), you need to search up from the last entry if you want the lowest non-zero.